# SqlAlchemy Left Join with count

Tags: python, count, sqlalchemy, left-join

```
class Employee
    id
    name

class Location
    id
    city

class Work
    id
    employee_id
    location_id
```

Todo: Left join with count (including zero)

Desired result

```
    location.city count
    NYC 10
    SFO 5
    CHI 0
```

Raw Query:

```
    select location.id, count(work.id) as count
    from location 
    left join work
    on location.id = work.location_id
    group by location.id
```

SqlAlchemy:

```
    db_session.query(Location, func.count.work_id).label('count')). \
                filter(location.id == work.location_id). \
                group_by(location._id). \
```

What is the right way to specify columns in select while doing a left join?

Answer (score 15):

Define a relationship between your tables when you define the orm model. See [this tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship). In your example, `Work` is a association table, so if you don't have any other data in `Work`, you can use a [many to many relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-many-to-many-relationship) e.g.:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class Work
    id
    employee_id
    location_id

class Employee
    id
    name

class Location
    id
    city
    employees = relationship(Employee, secondary=Work, backref='locations')
```

Then query:

```
session.query(Location, func.count(Work.id)).outerjoin(Work).group_by(Location)
```

As you have defined the relationship, sqlalchemy will know the direction, and columns for the `outerjoin`.

When you do the `group_by`, it is important to pass `Location` and not just `Location.id`, because by doing `select(Location)`, sqlalchemy will select all columns in Location, and so you must also pass all columns in Location.